# Invalid use of group by while showing username with heighest salary in group

Tags: mysql

I use **`MySQL`**

I wanted to show some records like Total Salary per designation , avg salary etc. All are working except : I want to show person name with heighest salary in group. When I use the query as below , I give error : `Invalid use of group function` . I ran it many times using different tweaks , ordering of query , still giving error. What may be the issue here ?

```
SELECT designation , SUM(salary) as salary_as_per_designation ,
        count(*) as num_employees ,
        avg(salary) as avg_salary , 
        MIN(salary) as min_salary_of_emp_per_designation, 
        MAX(salary) as max_salary_of_emp_per_designation , 
        (SELECT name FROM articles where salary = max(salary) GROUP BY designation LIMIT  1) as emp_name_min_sal 
FROM articles GROUP BY designation;
```

The weired thing is when i use on 2nd last line above like `.... where salary = 10000...`  100 as Some random value query works but gives wrong result , I mean wrong name for the user with heighest salary in group.

My table structure is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `salary` double NOT NULL,
  `designation` enum('tech_support','developer','tester','designer') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: And you use MySQL, MS SQL Server and Oracle here?

Comment: @jarlh , I use MySQL . I guess query will be same on all platform.

Comment: Still no need to tag products not used. If you want a general answer the "SQL" tag should be enough.

Comment: How can you use GROUP function in subquery? This query will genrate an error: **ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function**

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com iirc, at least oracle doesn't support `LIMIT`.

Comment: @collapsar , can we make a query which will run on Mysql + oracle ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com, avoid LIMIT construction, try to use ANSI SQL only. (Tip, the SQL Validator is a great time saver when writing portable  - ANSI - SQL: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml, just give a query and press "test SQL" and you'll know if the syntax is ANSI compliant.)

Comment: A couple of things to note: Your table has no PK, and money is normally DECIMAL, not DOUBLE.

Comment: @jarlh Um, and what is the ANSI SQL standard equivalent of LIMIT?

Comment: @Strawberry , It can be done later , but Query execution is main thing . This is prototype which I am going to implement on live after query is proper.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com If I needed help with a problem like this, I'd provide proper DDLs (and an sqlfiddle) TOGHETHER WITH the desired result set.

Comment: @Strawberry, FETCH FIRST is the ANSI SQL way. (Unfortunately not widely supported yet, but newer Oracle versions have it. Don't knwo about MySQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ilv.*,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
    FROM articles 
    where salary = ilv.max_salary_of_emp_per_designation 
   ) as emp_name_min_sal 
FROM 
(
SELECT designation , SUM(salary) as salary_as_per_designation ,
    count(*) as num_employees ,
    avg(salary) as avg_salary , 
    MIN(salary) as min_salary_of_emp_per_designation, 
    MAX(salary) as max_salary_of_emp_per_designation 
FROM articles 
GROUP BY designation
) AS ilv
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'ilv.max_salary_of_emp_per_designatio' in 'where clause' ` , it gave error after I executed it  :( .

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? Note sub-select conditions, you're looking for salaries within the designation grouping?

```
SELECT designation,
       SUM(salary) as salary_as_per_designation,
       count(*) as num_employees,
       avg(salary) as avg_salary, 
       MIN(salary) as min_salary_of_emp_per_designation, 
       MAX(salary) as max_salary_of_emp_per_designation, 
       (SELECT max(name)
        FROM articles
        where designation = a1.designation 
        and salary = (select max(salary) from articles
                      where designation = a1.designation)) as emp_name_min_sal 
FROM articles a1
GROUP BY designation;
```

Comment: I executed and got error -> `Unknown column 'a.designation' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Now fixed - but the error should have been obvious - we're trying to help you fix your problems, if you want someone to write the code for you, then you probably want another forum.

Comment: Can you please explain modification you did in your query ?

Comment: Use max(name) to make sure just one row returned. (FETCH FIRST/LIMIT/TOP would do, but this is portable), from the articles with salary = max(salary) for this designation group.

Answer (score -1):

Use this query instead,

```
SELECT MAX(salary) into @max_sal FROM articles;
SELECT designation , SUM(salary) as salary_as_per_designation ,
        count(*) as num_employees ,
        avg(salary) as avg_salary , 
        MIN(salary) as min_salary_of_emp_per_designation, 
        MAX(salary) as max_salary_of_emp_per_designation , 
        (SELECT name FROM articles where salary = @max_sal GROUP BY designation LIMIT  1) as emp_name_min_sal 
FROM articles GROUP BY designation;
```

Hope this will work, thank you.

Comment: It gives Same name say Dolly as emp name for all employes after executing.